# C#: ASP.NET ASMX Web Services вернуть response в формате SOAP

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, soap

У меня есть веб-сервис ASP.Net

```charp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace WebApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(int i)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
} 
}
```

Сейчас он возвращает такой XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World</string>
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы он возвращал это как сообщение SOAP?

Comment: А зачем вы используете ASMX? Почему не WCF?

Comment: Каким образом делаете вызов к сервису? asmx должен корректный soap-ответ возвращать.

Comment: Использую ASMX потому что нужно обращаться по URL к методам.(в начале как раз и был WCF, пробовал его сделать как REST, но также не получилось получить респонс в формате SOAP)


Вызов к серверу делаю через стандартную страницу либо через Soap UI